# Why is the drawContour() in OpenCV generating this strange Mask?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, contour

I started by reading in this `Mat`.

[image]

Then I converted it to Greyscale and applied `Imgproc.canny()` to it, getting the following mask.

[image]

Then I used `Imgproc.findContours()` to find the contours, `Imgproc.drawContours()`, and `Core.putText()` to label the contours with numbers:

[image]

Then I did `Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(0));
        Mat submatrix = new Mat();
        submatrix = originalMat.submat(boundingRect);` to get following `submatrix`:

[image]

**So far so good.** The Problem starts hereafter:

**NOW I NEEDED A MASK OF THE `submatrix`. So I decided to use `Imgproc.drawContours()` to get the mask:**

```
Mat mask = new Mat(submatrix.rows(), submatrix.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        List<MatOfPoint> contourList = new ArrayList<>();
        contourList.add(contours.get(0));
        Imgproc.drawContours(mask, contourList, 0, new Scalar(255), -1);
```

I got the following mask:

[image]

**WHAT I WAS EXPECTING was a filled (in white color) diamond shape on black background.**

**WHy am I getting this unexpected result?**

---

***EDIT:***

1. When I replaced `Mat mask = new Mat(submatrix.rows(),
   submatrix.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);` by [`Mat mask =
   Mat.zeros(submatrix.rows(), submatrix.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html),
   the last mask with white colored *garbage* was replaced by an empty
   black mask withOUT any white color on it. I got the following submat
   and mask:

   [image] [image]
2. I was getting the first contour in the list of contours (named
   `contours`) by `contours.get(0)`, and using this first contour to
   calculate `Imgproc.boundingRect()` as well as in
   `contourList.add(contours.get(0));` later (where `contourList` is
   the list of just one contour which will be used in the last
   `drawContours()`).

   Then I went ahead to change `contours.get(0)` to
   **`contours.get(1)`** in `Imgproc.boundingRect()` as well as in `contourList.add();` (just before `Imgproc.drawContours()`). That
   resulted in this submat and mask:

   [image]  [image]
3. Then I changed back to `contours.get(0)` in
   `Imgproc.boundingRect()`; and let
   `contourList.add(contours.get(1));` be there. Got the following
   submat and mask:

   [image]  [image]

**NOW I am completely Unable to Understand what is happening here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this is handle in JAVA (I usually use OpenCV in c++ or python), but there is an error in your code...

The `contours` list will have a list of list of points. This points will refer to the original image. So, this mean that if the figure one is in lets say, `x=300, y= 300, width= 100, height=100` then when you get your submatrix it will try to draw those points in a smaller image... so when it tries to draw point `(300,300)` in a 100 x 100 image, it will simply fail... probably throws an error or simply doesn't draw anything...

A solution for this is, do a for loop and substract to each point of the contour the initial point of the bounding rect (in my example `(300,300)`).

As, why there is some garbage drawn... well you never initialize the matrix. Not sure in JAVA, but in c++ you have to set them to 0.
I think it should be something like this:

```
Mat mask = new Mat(submatrix.rows(), submatrix.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
```

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

I think I did not explain myself clearly before.

Your contours are an array of points (x,y). These are the coordinates of the points that represent each contour in the **original image**. This image has a size, and your submatrix has a smaller size. The points are outside of this small image boundaries....

you should do something like this to fix it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < contours[0].length; j++) {
    contours[0][j].x -= boundingrect.x;
    contours[0][j].y -= boundingrect.y;
}
```

and then you can draw the contours, since they will be in boundaries of the submat.

I think in java it is also possible to subtract the opencv points directly:

```
for (int j = 0; j < contours[0].length; j++) {
    contours[0][j] -= boundingrect.tl();
}
```

but in this case I am not sure, since I have tried it in c++ only

`boundingrect.tl()` -> gives you the top left point of the rect

Comment: I had tried `new Mat(submatrix.rows(), submatrix.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));`, but that had not worked. But `Mat.zeros()` works. I tried a couple other things, which have confused me more. Can you see the edit at the bottom of my question?

Comment: Thank you so very much for solving my problem. I could not fully comprehend the initial answer, but thank you for clarifying in the edit. In Java I had to convert the contour (whose type is `MatOfPoint`) to an array of `Points` and then I manipulated the `x` and `y` coordinates of each `Point`: `Point[] pointsArray = contours.get(0).toArray();
   for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < pointsArray.length; pointIndex++) {
    pointsArray[pointIndex].x -= boundingRect.x;
    pointsArray[pointIndex].y -= boundingRect.y;
   }
contours.get(0).fromArray(pointsArray);`

Comment: @Solace No problem, I am a little rusty in my Java, so I wrote it the best I could... I am glad it worked out :)